# Unable to Load DLL 'sqlite.interop.dll' After Create Setup File

Tags: c#, .net, dll, sqlite

I am  working on a windows application using Visual studio 2015(Professional) and Sqlite DataBase, windows 8.1(x64). i Install Sqlite From Nuget it Autometically install These References... system.componentmodel.dataannotations, System.Data.SQLite, System.Data.SQLite.EF6, System.Data.SQLite.Linq .

when i execute my app in visual Studio, Everything is working Fine. then Publish it by Windows Setup. then Install The Newly Created Setup File on My machine windows 8.1(x64). Whenever i try to Run it and Click on Login Button it gives the following error

"**unable to load dll 'sqlite.interop.dll': the specified module could not be found. (exception from hresult: 0x8007007e)**".

[image]

my Code is...

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source = SampelTest.db; Version = 3; new = false; compress = true; ";    
private void buttonLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        using (SQLiteCommand sqlcmd = new SQLiteCommand("select count(*) from [SampelTest]", con))
                        {
                            con.Open();
                            Int32 count = Convert.ToInt32(sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar());
                            con.Close();
                            if (count > 0)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("User have in DataBase");
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Empty DataBase");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                    finally
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
```

My Database file in the Debug Folder  "SampelTest.db"i already tried these step that are from Google to resolve my problem.

1. Coppy Sqlite.Interop.dll File From x64 To Debug Folder.
   [image: ![enter image description here]
2. create x86 and x64 folder from solution Explorar and add Sqlite.Interop.dll from x86 and x64 respectively and Set Property, Build Option => Content, Copy to output Directory => Copy always.

[image]

3. Unchake the Prefer 32-bit.

[image]

After Try these steps can't able to solve this problem. Please Help to me to solve this. Thanks For Looking.

Comment: with the ones that are in the folders, are they send to `Copy Always` or `Copy If Newer`, also when debugging, Change `Platform Target ` to `X64`

Comment: I already Tried to Copy If Newer. and Platform Target also x64.

Comment: I had a similar issue once before, try restoring the nuget package

Comment: I am having the same issue too. The only way I managed to resolve it (seems kinda hackish) was to include the SQLite.Interop.dll in the setup wizard directory (Add a file to the setup package)

Comment: @Savlon. I also solved it following the same way.